# Calibrating Motic Camera to Stage Micrometer

Tags: microscopy

Whilst calibrating my Motic Microsope's camera, I am able to calibrate the 10x object lens against the stage micrometer accurately.  However when I calibrate (using the Motic 2.0 Plus software) the 40x object lens, it always sets the ratio incorrectly.

For example, in the calibration panel, I load a photo of the scale that I took and then I draw the circle so that it measures the pixels both in height and width and then I tell it that the circle is 10 µm.  But it doesn't seem to get the ratio correct.  When I did this for the 10x lens it worked perfectly.

So I took a photo of the scale with the 40x object lens and then went to calibrate that.

[image]
[image]

Here you can see how the calibration is performed: you position a circle over the photograph and tell it the size in µm (it's rather large, sorry):

[image]

Here you can see the measuring line out of whack.  It gives me 8 µm for a length that should only be 4 µm.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this was by using the *scale line* method.  First, I understand that each division on the stage micrometer is equal to 10 microns.  Then, using my photograph of my stage micrometer and the Motic software on my computer,  I draw a horizontal line over oh, say, 3 divisions and tell it that this distance (measured in pixels) is equal to 30 microns.

Now, using the same method, this is also possible:

I found another Windows program called [Meazure](http://www.cthing.com/Meazure.asp) which you can use in the same fashion without any special microsoft software.  For this I use XnView to open the photograph of my stage micrometer, set the zoom to 100% and then draw a straight line over oh, say, 3 divisions.  Then I see how many pixels long that is.  Then I tell Meazure that this many pixels is equal to 30 microns.  Now I can measure, in XnView, any image taken by the microscope's camera - I just have to remember to assure the view is exactly the same.

The Meazure program is *very* nice and easy to use, and I actually prefer it, although the Motic software provides labels and such that are useful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the shape is an ellipse rather than a circle. The ellipse has major and minor axes, which are described in terms of half-axes (177 and 175 pixels respectively). Is it possible the software is incorrectly using the half-axis measurements, whereas when you draw a perfect circle it will correctly use the diameter? This is consistent with the x and y scale numbers being different from each other.

So I would suggest re-calibrating with a perfect circle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I calibrate, should I calibrate to the edges of that black box?  It's supposed to represent 4µm.  If they were tick-marks I would think to measure to the insides...  It's kind of confusing.  Do I count the tick mark or not? Or do I measure to half of it?

Comment: With my own calibration slide that has a linear scale (like a ruler), I measure from the left side of one tick mark to the left side of another one.  I'm not familiar with your calibration slide, so I don't know what the outer lines represent. Do you have any documentation or are there other areas of the slide that are more clearly labeled?

Comment: My Mycologist says that it's supposed to be 10 microns from one tick to the next - whether left to left as you say (which is easy to see - thanks!) or from half to half of the tick.  So I tried this by capturing the scale with the 10x lens and calibrated four ticks to be 40 microns.  But when I measure from tick mark to tick mark I get 18.10 microns.  I'm still missing something.

Comment: My Stage Micrometer has five calibrators: a circle at 1.5mm, a circle at 0.6mm, a scale cross (1 DIV=0.01mm), a tiny circle at 0.15mm and a circle at 0.07mm.  Should I be using a particular one of these?

Comment: Okay, I think I've got this.  Instead of calibrating by drawing a circle over the scale cross, I used a different calibration setting where I just drew a straight line vertically and a different line horizontally.  with my Mycologist's directions that each length between tick marks = 10 µm I am now able to come up with correct dimensions.  Thanks for your time and attention!  Should I post this as it's own answer, or should you update yours to match so that I can accept a solution?

Comment: Great to hear that you solved it! I'm not a Stack Exchange expert, but I think the solution you found is different from my original idea. So for me, it makes sense for it to be its own answer.